# PHP Process With Threading Every 15 Seconds (Calling From PHP file not from Shell or other sources.)

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, process, cron

Good day. I have an issue to which i did not find an answer. Ideally and in short here how it goes.

I have a game called Mafia Role Play (Mobile part done now server side). So it has the timer which must be manipulated on the server side. The idea was the next :

• The user clicks on 'Start Game' button which is making the Post Request to my server PHP file,let's say the name is `StartGame.php`.

• That `StartGame.php` file MUST handle the rest. First it must start some process which will run in background and will run continuously every 15 seconds.

• The background process must iterate through the Database checking the date of the game start and comparing with the current date.

• If the date of the game start and the current date difference is greater or equal to the user specified maximum days,hours or minutes, the process must schedule an Event on the Mysql for self-destruction after 1 hour.

• After all this the process must send the Notification to the user mobile via Firebase API.

Ideally that is what i want to achieve. I am stuck at the process part and here are things that have been doing but never achieved a success.

1- I have used the `while()` loop with `sleep()` method but it freezes the echo and it will never reach to the echo,meaning the mobile will never get response from server. So it is out.

2- I tried to use the system_daemon library for PHP but i failed to manage it work as there was tons of errors given to me as soon as i made the post request and started the daemon process so it is out too.

3- The Cron jobs can not be used as they can be started only via shell and not from PHP file ,so i only need to start the process as soon as user started the game so the Cron job is not the way out either.

Without further ado , i have no clue what to do and what kind of library even to search for my server side PHP coding. Anyone has any ideas? Please help me out as this is killing me more then a month and i was not able to give it any solution yet.

I am asking for the next. How to start a process which will be started from the PHP file and will run every 15 seconds (the seconds,minutes or hours does not matter)?

Thank you for you'r time and patience.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I described the problem as you can see and as you can see too i have rowed the steps i have tried to achieve my goal which was failed,so for further achievement of the goal i need an help as i have no direction to look for at all as all the google results have been searched and used that is the main purpose for coming here.